# Python : Pyomo: problem contrainst 'Cannot convert non-constant expression to bool."

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a problem on the following form:

```
**model.obj= Objective(
        expr= sum([ cost_fonction( model.Q[((i1,j1),t)],  for (i1,j1) in Routes_reel for t in time])   ,sense=minimize)**
```

I would like add a conditionnal constrainst as like :
**model.reservoir_SM= Var(model.months,domain=NonNegativeReals,doc="Optimized stocks")
model.constraint_Saint_Michel= ConstraintList( )**

```
for t in time:
    if t<6: 
        model.constraint_Saint_Michel.add(
            model.reservoir_SM[t] == 0
            )
    elif t==6: 
        model.constraint_Saint_Michel.add(
        model.reservoir_SM[t] == Initial_Stock 
            )
    else  : 
          model.constraint_Saint_Michel.add(
          model.reservoir_SM[t] == model.reservoir_SM[t - 1] -np.maximum(0,(sum([model.Q[((i,j),t)] for (i,j) in Routes_SMA ]) - Vol_prelevable[t-1]))
                                       )
```

But i receive this error message :
Cannot convert non-constant expression to bool. This error is usually caused by using an expression in a boolean context such as an if statement. For example,
m.x = Var()
if m.x <= 0:
...
would cause this exception.

I try to force by using model.Q[((i,j),t)].value.
The model solves but the stock incrementation does not work correctly
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: in your `else` statement your using a `np.maximum` function which is not allowed to be used in the pyomo context. You need to reformulate that part of the constraint in order to apply it.

Comment: Hi, This is the point. I don't see how reformulate max(0, X1-X2) in order to be pyomo compatible.  However, i am going to replace max(0, X1-X2) by 0.5 * (X1-X2) +abs(X1-X2) but i don't think that is the good pyomo's way

Comment: You can use a new `Var` `z` and 2 new constraints such that: `model.z[t]>=0` and `model.z[t]>= sum([model.Q[((i,j),t)] for (i,j) in Routes_SMA ]) - Vol_prelevable[t-1]))` you need to be aware with indexes when using `t-1` but that's the main idea